# How to forbid WKWebView's horizontal bounce?

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

As the gif showed blow,I want to forbid the horizontal bounce,it's so ugly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this to stop bounces:

```
    self.webView.scrollView.bounces = false
```

**Update:**

To disable only horizontal bounce, you can use this code:

First set the webview's scrollview delegate to self

```
self.webView.scrollView.delegate = self
```

and then implement it like this.

```
extension UIViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate{
    public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if(scrollView.contentOffset.x < 0){
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y), animated: false)
        }else if (scrollView.contentOffset.x >= scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.frame.size.width) {
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.frame.size.width, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y), animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there a way only stop horizontal bounce?

Comment: Edited my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: i am using webkit in tableview cell and extension has no effect on that :\ ..